# How to add some custom text after a taxonomy field in panels?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, panels

I have a taxonomy field called cvtype.

This cvtype is containing several names like
- Standard
- Complete

I can add this to a Panel by adding content > node.
I would like to add the letters CV behind each term in this panel.

How to do this in D7?

Comment: You say `after a taxonomy field` in the title and then `behind each term` in the body text and it's not clear what you are trying to achieve, so could you please clarify? Why don't you just rename taxonomy terms?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `display suite` to add a prefix:

- Download & enable the module Display Suite (if not already installed) https://www.drupal.org/project/ds
- Go to `<my_url>/admin/structure/ds/settings`
- Enable export field templates
  [image]
- Edit your cvtype taxonomy and click on the Manage Display tab
  [image]
- Choose the one column layout (and save) -> display the name field, click the gears icon & add the prefix

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great solution but I'm working with Panels and with that this solution is not working.